# Ubuntu 15.10 software center closes immediately after launch

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 (total newcomer to linux in general, btw). The software center, as well as the ubuntu updater applications seem to close immediately after opening. the terminal came up with the following reaction to starting software-center:

```
2015-12-06 19:55:36,309 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
2015-12-06 19:55:36,358 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-12-06 19:55:36,361 - softwarecenter.db.database - ERROR - failed to add apt-xapian-index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 194, in _get_new_xapiandb
    softwarecenter.paths.APT_XAPIAN_INDEX_DB_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xapian/__init__.py", line 3667, in __init__
    _xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't stat '/var/lib/apt-xapian-index/index' (No such file or directory)
2015-12-06 19:55:36,837 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-12-06 19:55:36,840 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2015-12-06 19:55:36,878 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 168, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py:190: Warning: Source ID 70 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main_iteration()
2015-12-06 19:55:37,523 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

This is too much info for someone like me. Can somebody please interpret what's happening to my machine?

PS: I was trying to download the spotify software before attempting to open the software updater. It failed and I don't know why. Maybe it plays a role in what you see...

Thanks!
Kaiser

Comment: Can you please post the output you get from doing `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` (or whatever other method you want to use to show us that file)? It sounds like you have something wrong with that file according to the error message.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

Answer (score 1):

Open the file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` with a command like this:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Clear out the lines currently in the file (at least the line that starts with sudo).

Add this in:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Run (this will trust the spotify software source):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
```

Then run (this will update the list of available software):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally, run (this will install spotify using the command line. At this point, I think you should have a working software center that you could also do this through):

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: Instead of using `gksudo gedit` to open and edit the file, you could also just overwrite it from the command-line: `echo 'deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!

So I went and typed in the suggestion from azendale. since gksu is not installed yet (new installation), the terminal suggested that I install it via `sudo apt-get install gksu` 

When I commanded that, I got: `Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package gksu`

Comment: here is the full documentation of what I did so far.

http://imgur.com/RkYG9Nj 

http://imgur.com/ZXZsiEU

Comment: @HarterKaiser, ok, try the command Byte Commander said instead. I didn't realize gksudo doesn't come by default. (I was trying to go the easy GUI route, but Byte Commander's suggestion should work just fine as a substitute).